# how does CUDA schedule its threads

Tags: cuda

i've got a few questions regarding cuda's scheduling system.

A.When i use for example the foo<<<255, 255>>() function, what actually happens inside of the card? i know that each SM receives from the upper level a block to schedule, and each SM is responsible to schedule its incoming BLOCK, but which part does it? if for example i've got 8 SMs, when each of each contains 8 small CPUs, is the upper level responsible to schedule the remaining 255*255 - (8 * 8) threads?

B.What's the limit of maximum threads that one can define? i mean `foo<<<X, Y>>>();` x,y =?

C. Regarding the last example, how many threads can be inside of one block? can we say that the more blocks / threads we have, the faster the execution will be?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A. The compute work distributor will distribute a block from the grid to a SM. The SM will convert the block in warps (WARP_SIZE = 32 on all NVIDIA GPUs). Fermi 2.0 GPUs each SM has two warp schedulers which share a set of data paths. Every cycle each warp scheduler picks a warp and issues an instruction to one of data paths (please don't think of CUDA cores). On Fermi 2.1 GPUs each warp scheduler has independent data paths as well as a set of shared data paths. On 2.1 every cycle each warp scheduler will pick a warp and attempt to dual issue instructions for each warp.

The warp schedulers attempt to optimize the use of data paths. This means that it is possible that a single warp will execute multiple instructions in back to back cycle or the warp scheduler can choose to issue from a different warp every cycle.

The number of warps/threads that each SM can handle is specified in the CUDA Programming Guide v.4.2 Table F-1. This scales from 768 threads to 2048 threads (24-64 warps).

B. The maximum threads per launch is defined by the maximum GridDims * the maximum threads per block. See Table F-1 or refer to the documentation for cudaGetDeviceProperties.

C. See the same resources as (B). The optimum distribution of threads/block is defined by your algorithm partitioning and is influenced by the occupancy calculation. There are observable performance impacts based around problem set size of the warps on the SM and the amount of time blocked at instruction barriers (among other things). For starters I recommend at least 2 blocks per SM and ~50% occupancy.

Answer (score 0):

B. It depends on your device. You can use the cuda function `cudaGetDeviceProperties` to see the specifications for your device. A common maximum number is y=1024 threads per block and x=65535 blocks per Grid dimension.

C.A common practise is to have powers of 2 (128,256,512 etc.) threads/block. Reducing large arrays is very effective that way (see [Reduction](http://www.uni-graz.at/~haasegu/Lectures/GPU_CUDA/Lit/reduction.pdf)). The optimum distribution of blocks and threads actually depends on your application and your hardware. I personally use 512 threads/block for large sparse linear algebra computations on a TeslaM2050 since it's the most efficient for my applications.